# JQuery function is constantly failing but I am not sure why

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a multiprint button to grab all the reservation on todays day and generate all the pdfs at once to print. I have the generatepdf action that works properly by itself. the multiprint button correctly grabs the correct ids. but the function to multiprint is throwing errors.

```
    <script>
        function multiPrintComments() {
            var selectedRestaurantId = $("#restaurantDropdown").val();

            if (!selectedRestaurantId) {
                alert("Please select a restaurant.");
                return;
            }

            // Perform an AJAX request to get reservations for the selected restaurant
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetReservationsForRestaurant", "Reservations")",
                data: { restaurantID: selectedRestaurantId },
                success: function (reservations) {
                    console.log("Selected Restaurant ID:", selectedRestaurantId);
                    console.log("Fetched Reservations:", reservations);

                    // Loop through the fetched reservations and generate comments sheets
                    for (var i = 0; i < reservations.length; i++) {
                        console.log("Generating comments sheet for Reservation ID:", reservations[i].id);
                        generateCommentsSheet(reservations[i].id);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed to fetch reservations for the selected restaurant.");
                }
            });
        }

        // Function to generate a comments sheet for a reservation
        function generateCommentsSheet(reservationID) {
            // Perform an AJAX request to generate the comments PDF
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Reservations/GenerateCommentSheetPDF?reservationID=" + reservationID,
                data: { reservationID: reservationID },
                success: function (response) {
                    // Create a temporary link to download the generated PDF
                    var link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
                    link.download = "Comments_" + reservationID + ".pdf";
                    link.click();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed to generate comments PDF for reservation ID: " + reservationID);
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
```

```
        public IActionResult GetReservationsForRestaurant(int restaurantID)
        {
            // Implement logic to fetch reservations for the selected restaurant on the current day
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            var reservations = _context.Reservations
                .Where(r => r.RestaurantID == restaurantID && r.ArrivalDateTime.Date == currentDate)
                .ToList();

            return Json(reservations);
        }
```

I think the problem lies here. specifically in the generatecommentsheets function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ' multiprint is throwing errors'. Include those errors to give us a chance to help, we can't guess.

Comment: Also, you should learn to debug your code, step through it and check variables are correct.